# Only command prompt is appearing after upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: command-line, 16.04

I have upgraded to from Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 16.04. How to get the Unity desktop?

Comment: after logging in do a `startx` see if that helps

Answer (score 0):

Press the SHIFT key after the Power On Self Test but while GRUB is loading. Select "Advanced Options" and choose an earlier kernel version to boot.

I've also been having trouble with Kernel version 4.4.0.34 and I'm using an Intel Socket 775 system.

Hopefully, this helps.